# Alt key focuses window's main menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wine

I'm using GNOME as my desktop environment. When i'm working with one specific application with Wine when I press Alt key the focus switches from application area to it's main menu, which causes some problems with the program. On Windows pressing alt doesn't focus main menu. This behavior is not really useful for me and it's OK for me to disable it system-wide. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, in Windows, the Alt key *does* trigger the main menu, and since you're on Wine, you're probably using a Windows application, so this behavior is normal... In Windows...

Comment: As I said, on Windows in that specific application the Alt key does not trigger the main menu.

Comment: I got it the other way around. You might want to re-read your question, because it's a bit confusing, but anyway, what is the application we're talking about?